# Serve mpeg stream from remote file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a problem with streaming remote video mpg file using Express. When I open the page, it loads infinitely without giving any error. I want to serve video in the browser but couldn't make it out. How can I do it?

```
liveStream.get('/', cors(), (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'video/mpeg'})
  request('example.com/facecam01.mpg').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('facecam01.mpg'))
})
```

Comment: You're piping it into another file, you should be able to just `.pipe(res)`

Comment: Yes, I reached that file. But now it downloads the file on browser, doesn't show the video :/

Comment: I don't think browsers natively support mpg streams, you're going to need some sort of player.

Comment: `But now it downloads the file on browser, doesn't show the video` what does that have to do with the code you've shown, that downloads the file to the SERVER?

Comment: @JaromandaX After this: fs.createReadStream('./facecam01.mpg').pipe(res) code, when I open browser, it forces download.

Comment: I think [Supported media formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) will show you why - as mentioned by Ben Fortune, browsers do not support *mpg* streams

Comment: Video streaming both on the client and server side is fairly complicated. For fairly small files it can be simple but if you need navigation or controls it gets very complicated very quickly - https://medium.com/canal-tech/how-video-streaming-works-on-the-web-an-introduction-7919739f7e1

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you need to pipe to the response: 
   `request('example.com/facecam01.mpg').pipe(res)`.
2. You need to send partial content of files. See example https://github.com/daspinola/video-stream-sample